# GraphViz dot Circular Node Alignment

Tags: graphviz, dot, circos

How to use Graphviz to align nodes circular in clusters with additional text? Optionally with identical node positions (always 8 nodes per cluster)?
[image: Intended Alignment]

I tried `circo`, however, faced some shortcomings:

- No clustering
- No comments
- Problems with margins for larger labels (10+ char)
- Alignment varies with label size

[This (Graphviz Online)](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#graph%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0Alayout%20%3D%20circo%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0Anode%20%5Bshape%20%3D%20circle%2C%0D%0A%09%20%20fontname%20%3D%20Helvetica%2C%0D%0A%09%20%20margin%20%3D%200%5D%0D%0A%09%20%20%0D%0Aedge%20%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Asubgraph%201%20%7B%0D%0Aa1%20--%20b1%20--%20c1%20--%20d1%20--%20e1%20--%20f1%20--%20g1%20--%20h1%20--%20a1%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Asubgraph%202%20%7B%0D%0Aa%20--%20b%20--%20c%20--%20d%20--%20e%20--%20f%20--%20g%20--%20h%20--%20a%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D), nothing spectacular, was the closest I could get. Any hints to other layouts (or even tools) appreciated.

```
graph {

layout = circo;

node [shape = circle,
      fontname = Helvetica,
      margin = 0]

edge [style=invis]

subgraph 1 {
a1 -- b1 -- c1 -- d1 -- e1 -- f1 -- g1 -- h1 -- a1
}

subgraph 2 {
a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f -- g -- h -- a
}
}
```

Comment: Please show what you got so far as starting point for others to correct / complete.

Comment: Hi @albert. Did you check the link below "This (Graphviz Online)" - I tried a lot, but although this snippet is quite simple, it was the closest I could achieve. I am about to write an alternative answer right now.

Comment: No I didn't (to my shame) but I think it i nearly always better to include the (short) source code as links might not be not persistent (in the future) and also giving a better reading as one directly can see the code and doen't have to click to another site.

Comment: Okay, got it, sorry for that. I thought it is convenient to directly jump into, but you are right, a broken link in the future is highly likely. Will edit my Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the answer as I was asking for (Graphviz), but I found a much nicer solution with MATLAB. It was about plotting a seating plan for an event.

[image: Seating Plan Plot]

What I did broken down:

- `imread()` image of the floor plan
- Roughly determined pixel spacing, used as x & y vector for `image()` so that tables are in scale with the room.
- Manually defined centers for the clusters (here tables) with the help of `ginput()` (or `imellipse()`)
- Plotted circles with `plot()` and added text with `text()`